# monitor outgoing sms

Tags: android

hi Can anyone tell me is there a way to monitor outgoing sms...
i want to create an app which will monitor outgoing sms and block texting in a particular region or when user is driving...
can anyone tell me how it is possible?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible. Don't limit the phone's functionality. It's the user's responsibility to not text while driving

Answer (score 1):

I saw an app called iZUP that might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way probably is not to try to block the texting in the code path but to get in front of the texting app. You can poll all foreground apps while driving is detected and lock the screen if a texting app is launched.

Other than that, you will need to do framework modification to really block outgoing text.

Comment: +1  He might as well go full 1984 at this point.  Why just block someone from texting while driving?  They shouldn't even be touching their phone.

Comment: Probably for parental control sort of application.